# attribute aligned crossplatform

Tags: c++, c++11

Is GCC's

```
union uint128_t {
    uint64_t q[2];
    uint64_t w[8];
    char b[16];
} __attribute__((aligned (16)));
```

is the same as (crossplatform):

```
union alignas(16) uint128_t {
    uint64_t q[2];
    uint64_t w[8];
    char b[16];
};
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  See [`__attribute__((aligned))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) and [`alignas`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas).

If you are asking "why does <some library> use `__attribute__` rather than `alignas`?"  I suspect the the answer is "because `alignas` is relatively new, but `__attribute__` has been supported for much longer."